# URL rewrite loses Virtual Directory prefix using JavaScript root-based urls

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

We have some third-party service on http://localhost:1234/, and we want to be able to access it externally via https://my-site.com/MyService/

For that we have IIS with Virtual Directory (Application) **MyService** and URL rewrite rule

```xml
<rule name="my-service" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1234/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This service renders html with some root urls like `<a href="/page1.html">Page 1</a>`

But following such links will lead us to https://my-site.com/<strike>MyService/</strike>page1.html

In order to fix it we have another URL rewrite outbound rule

```xml
<rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
  <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" negate="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="https://my-site.com/MyService/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And it works fine and renders absolute urls `<a href="https://my-site.com/MyService/page1.html">Page 1</a>`

However, if we have JavaScript

```js
// redirect
location.href = "/page2.html";

// AJAX
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/page2.html");
xhr.send();

// fetch
fetch("/page2.html");
```

those root-based urls will be resolved as https://my-site.com/<strike>MyService/</strike>page2.html

As this service is third-party, I can't just go to modify all those JavaScript code to include **/MyService** prefix. And those urls such as **/page2.html** are constructed dynamically so it's impossible to just use URL rewrite module to fixup corresponding JavaScript.

I was trying to add URL rewrite to the root website to capture such urls via http referer

```xml
<rule name="MyService" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(?!MyService).+$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="https://my-site.com/MyService*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-site.com/MyService/{R:0}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

but it still doesn't work properly and behaves very fragile.

Is there a way to solve such supposedly very common task easily?

Comment: I suggest you distinguish page1.html in the a tag from page1.html in JavaScript. The best way is to name it differently.

Comment: @samwu thanks, I modified to page2.html to avoid confusion